# JPGs and others get converted in UDIM

Tags: texturing, materials

I need a little help. whenever I would like to import an jpg (or an other fileformat like png etc.) as texture for an object, the file gets an udim and doesn´t work. So the object on which the texture should be gets pink and I really have no idea how to fix this. It´s a simple plane with one image on it. No complicated tiling or hi res stuff. Just one plane and one picture. (I can import Picture as a plane, but till 2.9 this method worked fine). Any hint would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When selecting your texture, select the gear icon on the top right corner of the blender file view window and disable the "Detect UDIMs" checkbox.
[image]